# Как изменить title кнопки "поделиться"?

Tags: javascript, hover

Проблема с яндекс share, добавляю vkontakte, facebook, twitter,
при hover у кнопки vkontakte атрибут "vkontakte" клиент хочет при hover title 'VK'.

Как изменить title кнопки при hover, в доке перепробовал всё, ничего не получается:

```
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
  <div id="my-share"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   
   var myShare = document.getElementById('my-share');

   var share = Ya.share2(myShare, {
       content: {
       
       },
       contentByService: {
           vkontakte: {
               title: 'VKtest',
           }
       }
   });


  </script>
```

Есть конечно вариант бахнуть просто так:

```
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            $('a.ya-share2__link[title="VKontakte"]').attr('title', 'VK');
        });
```

Но возможно есть решение более качественное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для манипуляций с блоком лучше использовать [hooks](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/api-docpage/). Например с помощью *onready*, которое при инициализации блока срабатывает. Ссылку на ВКонтакте можно отобрать по селектору `.ya-share2__item_service_vkontakte a`.

Итого:

```js
let share = Ya.share2('share', {
  hooks: {
    onready: function() {
      let vk = document.querySelector(".ya-share2__item_service_vkontakte a");
      vk.setAttribute("title", "VKTest");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>

<div id="share"></div>
```